# Can Anyone Identify This strange cockroach looking bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am looking for someone to identify this bug:
location india. It flew from my window in my room, killed it by spraying cockroach killer spray, it could fly like cockroach.

[image: Top view]

[image: View from down]

Comment: If you were a Jainist, I believe you wouldn't have killed it, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a mole cricket. Family Gryllotalpidae. They generally live underground, but as you noticed, they can fly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_cricket